# Are Retrofit requests executed in UI Thread?

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit, synchronous

I am a little bit confused. I know that Retrofit allows both Synchronous and Asynchronous requests, but are those requests made in the UI Thread?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous requests are made on whatever thread you are on at the time. If that is the main application thread (UI thread), then you will be attempting to have Retrofit do network I/O on the main application thread. You will crash with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Asynchronous requests are made on a background thread, not the main application thread.